# Cordova Google Maps Div Blank

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

i have been working on this issue all day and i have finally given up and am going to ask the question on here i have tried a lot of things from google search to solve this but so far i am yet to find an solution.

i have been trying to add google maps to my Cordova app today i updated all my plugins and cordova version to lastest also the google services

i added the plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps and i have the API keys and they are working.

i have created using the sample code. but the div not matter what i do is always blank bu if a use the fullscreen button and it shows a dialog with the map in it come up fine as a full screen map in IOS and Android but i am trying to get a map within a div.

all the code and screen images below when i press then full screen button it comes up with a full screen map but i am trying to get a map to show in the div above the the full screen button.

Javascript for map

```
var map;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  var divMap = document.getElementById("mainMap");
  // Initialize the map view
  map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(divMap);
  // Wait until the map is ready status.
  map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
}, false);

function onMapReady() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
}

function onBtnClicked() {
  map.showDialog();
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="map-page" data-role="page" >
            <div data-role="header" data-id="header1" class="ui-header">
                <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" >Back</a>
                <h1>Maps</h1>
            </div> 
                <div id="mainMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;margin-top:50px;"> </div>
                <button id="button">Full Screen</button>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the cordova-plugin-googlemaps plugin places map view under the browser view,
the browser (HTML elements) must be transparent.

So you can not set background image.

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Map/README.md#how-does-the-plugin-work